# Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }

Tags: php, google-api, gmail-api

I've looked around at the many questions about this problem and can't seem to find a solution.

My access token was expired and I'm using my latest refresh token with all my client information.

```
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($client_id);
    $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
    $client->setAccessType("offline");
    $client->addScope("https://mail.google.com/");

    $client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
```

I can access google's api with my access token however once it expires and I try and refresh it like above I get the error `Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }`

Everything on my part seems to be up to date and tested this includes :

- Access and refresh tokens
- Client information
- Server time is correct
- Application set as 'web application' in console

Comment: what exactly is `$refreshToken`?

Comment: My refresh token: e.g. -> 1/61QmgzgsUbbrszxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyxxxxx5jSpoR30zcRFq6 I got it a long with an access token which expired.

Comment: There are 2 common problems that cause invalid_grant errors:

1. Your server's clock is out of sync with NTP
2. You've exceeded the refresh token limit.
If you're using a single refresh token to generate access tokens frequently, then this could be the root of the problem.